# cxGrid concat column in summaryGroup

Tags: delphi, tcxgrid

I have a cxGrid, as below in the picture. 
I want to concatenate text in the group header of the second column, something like written in red.

Could you please help me?  I tried to modify text in the GetText method for the summary, but I didn't find a concatenate function.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, don't you know that you can use the `+` operator to concatenate strings?

Comment: can u share a portion of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [DevExpress Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T434996/modifying-group-header-via-customdrawgroupcell), you can customize the text in the Group headings by using the GroupGetDisplayText method of the grid.  An example is:

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1GroupGetDisplayText(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableItem; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord;
  var AText: string);
begin
  if ARecord is TcxGridGroupRow then
    AText := AText + 'Some additional text for testing';  // You can replace this with code to represent your time intervals
end;
```